# Getting to Know Stack Overflow's Voting Culture

Tags: support, faq, downvotes, voting, upvotes

There are few topics more controversial than voting, either on the Main site or here on Meta. Whether expressed in rants on Meta or rants in comments, users frequently get angry, confused and frustrated that their post has been downvoted.

We see pleas to "... be gentle on the downvoting!"<sup>1</sup> and accusations that Stack Overflow is "... un-welcoming to people trying to learn!"<sup>2</sup> Displeasure with downvoting in particular resulted in an effort to close the loop - [encouraging newer users to explain their downvote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes). One of the most highly upvoted posts on Meta includes the exhortation to ["rein in the downvoting a bit"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9953/could-we-please-be-a-bit-nicer-to-new-users).

The Help Center includes a couple sections on voting, including [Why is Voting Important?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote) and [Voting is different on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta).

A [recent post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193884/a-proposal-for-more-constructive-downvoting-on-meta-express-disagreement-by-ans) by a high rep user attempted to start a discussion over redefining voting on Meta.

Despite all the documentation and high quality answers to previously asked questions, there is still a common angst over the meaning of a vote and its effect on reputation. This is exacerbated by confusion over the "rules" of voting. The current FAQ's language appears to set rules for how people *should* vote, yet experienced users know that this is not a rule so much as an [unofficial recognition](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194042/bifurcation-of-voting-standards-and-the-perils-of-tag-editing#comment609247_194044) of existing patterns of behavior.

So, for the sake of new users (and the occasionally confused experienced user), it may be helpful to explain the nature of voting both on the Main site and on Meta. Not how to click the button, but the theory, reality and primarily the culture of the democratic process on Stack Overflow and how it works out in specific questions.

[Return to FAQ index](/q/251225)

---

*Please keep in mind that the following documented examples are meant only for reference. If you've come across them for the first time as the result of this question, please consider witholding your votes so as to avoid the "Meta effect".*

<sup>1</sup> https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194467/downvoting-revisited (now deleted)
<sup>2</sup> [Why do I receive downvotes when I am genuinely trying to learn?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/180692/why-do-i-receive-downvotes-when-i-am-genuinely-trying-to-learn)

Answer (score 80):

> *This post was written to document voting patterns in the Stack Overflow community, especially those which are not covered in the help center and which seem to cause the most confusion and frustration among new (and even some more experienced) users.*
>
> *This post is not meant to act as a defense for voting/democracy in general (that's adequately [covered in the help center](//stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote)), nor as a defense for any one particular pattern. The intent is to document why some people vote the way they do, **not** how they, or others, **ought** to vote.*
>
> *Use caution when looking for advice - this post is not meant to provide suggestions for how individual users should vote nor how posters should form their questions/answers. Advice for [how to effectively use your vote](//stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote) is covered by the help center. Jon Skeet, a prominent member of Stack Overflow, has written two excellent articles full of advice for [asking](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and [answering](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2009/02/17/answering-technical-questions-helpfully/) questions.*

Before anything else, it is essential to understand the following two simple, incontrovertible facts:

> **You may vote however you want to for any reason you want to<sup>†</sup>.**

> **Other members may vote however they want to for any reason they want to<sup>†</sup>.**

<sup>†</sup>There are a few algorithms to prevent [vote abuse](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/12/vote-fraud-and-you/) and [vote fraud](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/03/more-voting-anomalies/), but only to protect the sanctity of the vote - no further. Beyond fraudulent or abusive behavior, as a member of the community, you may vote however you want to for any reason you want to and other members may vote however they want to for any reason they want to. *(Keep in mind that, like voting for the political candidate with the best hair, your vote has consequences even if you are just goofing around. If you respect the site's [mission](https://blog.codinghorror.com/introducing-stackoverflow-com/), you'll learn to vote wisely.)*

It's helpful to understand that voting is intentionally open-ended. From the very beginning, Stack Overflow was designed to be a "[collective programmer community](https://blog.codinghorror.com/stack-overflow-none-of-us-is-as-dumb-as-all-of-us/)". As Jeff Atwood, a co-founder of the site, put so succinctly:

> "But **who cares what *I* think**; my opinion holds no particular weight. I'm just a member. This is **our** site."

While the rules and features of the site are [governed by the owners](http://blog.codinghorror.com/listen-to-your-community-but-dont-let-them-tell-you-what-to-do/) and moderators, the content is (almost entirely) curated by regular members via the democratic process of voting.

All of the content and patterns below must be seen through this prism. Whatever patterns exist and however users are encouraged to vote, in the end each individual may vote however they want to. If a user feels strongly about a post, about the content, the tone or the formatting, that user is not required to read this post, or any other, to determine the norms and appropriate patterns for how to cast their vote - they'll just vote, *and that's acceptable*.

This may be (and often enough is) difficult for some newer members to understand or accept. There have been many attempts (via Meta posts) to change the rules and/or patterns of voting to suit the needs or desires of an individual or a minority. These efforts have, almost universally, been soundly rejected by the larger community.

Though voting is up to the individual and therefore a bit messy and difficult to predict, we don't have total chaos. There are certain patterns and norms most experienced users are aware of and adhere to. Like tipping your waitress, these are not *requirements* - your account is not in danger of deletion if you abide by an unusual set of standards (as long as they aren't fraudulent or abusive) - but they are common and expected within our site's culture. Put simply:

- On **Stack Overflow**, users generally vote based on their perception of the **quality of the post** (well researched/high value/interesting/correct).
- On **Meta**, users generally vote based on their perception of the **quality of the post** (well researched/high value/interesting/correct) or, absent quality issues, if the user believes that the post contains a *proposal*, **the premise of the post** (agreement).

Within these general patterns are subsets of more specific behavior. Remember though - these are behavioral *patterns* which have evolved over time and *are not prescriptive*. They may help explain the votes on a particular question, but then again it could just be that the voter was responding to the OP's* profile picture.

*(The names below are entirely chosen to be fun and memorable and are, in no way, official)*

## Stack Overflow

- **XY Blindside** A question which may appear to be well researched on the surface and adheres to [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) *could* still attract downvotes if it falls afoul of the [X Y Problem](/q/66377).

  - A classic example: trying to parse HTML with a Regex<sup>S1</sup>.
- **Could Contain Treenuts** An answer which is technically correct (in that it demonstrably solves the OP's problem) *could* attract downvotes if it appears to advocate (or, at least, does not adequately disclaim) a practice which is held by some to be unwise or dangerous.

  - For example, in answer to a PHP question<sup>S2</sup>, a user provided a solution that was technically correct but some users felt was dangerous due to, among other things, SQL-injection vulnerabilities.
  - Voting based on code styles that have [fallen out of favor](/q/196355/191410) has been discussed on Meta, as well as code that may have [dangerous side effects](/q/276496).
- **Jester Effect** Some answers which may appear to have trouble fitting within the site's guidelines have just the right amount of humor or interest to generate a significant number of upvotes.

  - For example, a question querying users for an efficient sock sorting algorithm<sup>S3</sup> garnered a tremendous number of upvotes, despite some users' concerns<sup>S4</sup>
  - NOTE: It is generally unwise to depend on your wit to outmaneuver the [question guidelines](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).
- **Guilty by Association** Users are generally encouraged to vote on the merits of the post only, not on the [merits of the user](/q/193867) or, for answers, [the question](/q/194963). That said, some users may feel swayed (either to vote one way rather than another, or to vote rather than to not vote) based on the context, [tone](/q/71917) and/or [author](/q/515) of the post. Some users may upvote a "meh" question [due to a stellar answer](/a/209627). Some users may [downvote a decent answer to an obnoxious question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362204/should-i-flag-a-comment-begging-for-votes#comment549940_362204).
- **Rep Farming** A noticeable pattern of valuing reputation over quality, or an attempt to game the system by obviously abusing the site's tools without technically violating the rules, can attract the ire (and thus downvotes) of ordinary users. For example:

  - Answering obviously off-topic questions was [discussed on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194963/should-one-downvote-answers-to-off-topic-questions) at length, where many users indicated that this is how they vote in such circumstances.
  - A history of asking questions that are technically allowed but that may demonstrate bad faith (specifically, asking easy questions to get more attention and thus reputation) has led some users to [retributive voting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/23653/191410).
- **Secret Society** Some users may apply a slightly different set of standards for niche or newer technologies, allowing some questions to remain open and upvoted when they might not have been if asked of a more general, established technology. (It should be noted that this behavior has been [explicitly discouraged](/a/195773).)

  - In discussions on Meta, some users have observed that the readership of certain tags are [less likely to close](/a/188414) certain kinds of off-topic questions. Other users have suggested that newer technologies, specifically, be given a little leniency<sup>S5</sup>. However, this attitude is not well documented and neither post represents significant consensus on this issue.
- **Meta Effect** A post which initially received little or lopsided attention may experience a wave of interest if it is subsequently referenced or discussed on Meta. This may result in an increased volume of votes or in "corrective" actions.

  - For example, a discussion on Meta about the [quality of certain regex questions](/q/188408) contained links to several example questions. The questions were downvoted and closed within an exceptionally short period of time (though it was later suggested that some of them [should not have been](/q/188408#comment580221_188408)).
  - In another example, a [Meta post](/q/317470) led to hundreds of votes over two days on a question and answer that had sat idle for 9 months. The voting appeared to many to be lop-sided (strongly favoring an answer that may have not been completely accurate and disfavoring a question that had no clear issues) leading to one highly voted comment describing the situation as "[obscene](/q/317470/?cb=1#comment312632_317470)".
- **Interloper Effect** Similar to the "Meta effect", any question which gains significant attention via a third-party link or a fluke of the multi-collider's [hotness formula](/q/192046), may result in unusually robust voting activity.

  - This effect can be seen in a [Java question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/18719959/timeline) which contained an elementary mistake. First, the question generated a quick succession of answers which elevated it in the hotness ranking resulting in an unusual number of upvotes, but was later [called out](/q/197111) on Meta resulting in a sudden wave of downvotes.
- *Please add more...*

## Meta Stack Overflow

- **Trojan Horse** An assertion or proposal embedded within a discussion question, even if the OP intended to remain neutral, could attract downvotes from users who disagree with the proposal or assertion. In some cases, simply asking the question may be interpreted as making a proposal.

  - For example, a user posted the question "What can I do to improve my question?"<sup>M1</sup> but included the assertions that the original question was "excessively downvoted" for "no apparent reason" which some users felt were inaccurate*.
  - In another example, the OP, in an effort to remain neutral, asked to discuss "the pros and cons" of implementing a new feature<sup>M2</sup> and voters largely responded to it as a feature-request*.
- **Superlative Effect** The use of unsubstantiated superlatives as a core foundation for a feature-request or discussion can attract downvotes.

  - For example, a user posted an opinion that "lots of" good questions were being closed as subjective<sup>M3</sup>, but failed to provide even one example - which many (11+) users took issue with.
- **Bandwagon Tipping** A feature-request on Meta, which may have initially received many upvotes and/or positive attention, may be less well received on subsequent posts, though these downvotes may also be prompted by post quality concerns (in that the question is not well-researched).

  - For example, a suggestion to add bold formatting to code blocks<sup>M4</sup> was proposed in 2009 and was extremely popular. A duplicate suggestion in 2011<sup>M5</sup> proved to be far less popular. This effect was explicitly mentioned in [this comment](/q/208087#comment663347_208088).
- *Please add more...*

---

*Please keep in mind that the following documented examples are meant only for reference. If you've come across them for the first time as the result of this question, please consider withholding your votes so as to avoid the "Meta effect".*

<sup>S1</sup> [How to retrieve the value using a regular expression in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12197600)

<sup>S2</sup> [Store IP address with the submitted data in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13520943/211627) (10k rep required to see it).

<sup>S3</sup> [How can I pair socks from a pile efficiently?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14415881)

<sup>S4</sup> [Is a question asking for an algorithm to sort socks into pairs on-topic?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164379)

<sup>S5</sup> [Why isn't this question opinion based?](/a/195657)

<sup>M1</sup> [Excessive downvoting for no apparent (or explained) reason?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194250)

<sup>M2</sup> [Should downvote-without-comment rate remain unpublished?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193762)

<sup>M3</sup> [Lots of closes (as subjective) on good questions, recently](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108128)

<sup>M4</sup> [Bold code in a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32705)

<sup>M5</sup> [Can you enable bolding/italicising of text within code samples?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97383)

*OP stands for "Original Poster", the original author of the question or answer under discussion