# People voting to close a question for the wrong reasons

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, downvotes

I am no perfect questioner and I will admit I have asked my fair share of bad questions... but this time, although my question was a duplicate, I believe it contained a sufficient amount of information to answer the question. In fact, someone answered the question perfectly within 2/3 minutes of posting. However, it still got 3 votes towards closing the question because of insufficient information to diagnose the problem. As well as a number of downvotes, that I thought were completely unwarranted.

And I have been seeing this a lot, not just for me. People ask questions, but people refuse to read the whole thing or think about it for a second and they throw out downvotes because it's to hard for them to understand.

Could someone please tell me if I am crazy or not to believe that peoples votes to close the questions should've been towards a duplicate question instead of insufficient information?

Here is the question: [Div overflow beyond browser width without setting width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23573557/div-overflow-beyond-browser-width-without-setting-width)

It's just a little frustrating when you ask a completely reasonable and valid question yet people throw around downvotes.

Comment: Adding the content of your codepen link into the question could possible have avoided some of it.

Comment: You should note that it isn't too late to fix it. If you edit the question it should get placed in the reopen review queue.

Comment: See also: `(1)` [Getting to Know Stack Overflow's Voting Culture](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251487/456814), and `(2)` [When is it justifiable to downvote a question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252677/456814).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> However, it still got 3 votes towards closing the question because of insufficient information to diagnose the problem.
>
> [...]
>
> It's just a little frustrating when you ask a completely reasonable and valid question yet people throw around downvotes.

Downvotes and close votes are not related.

Your question was closed ( I cast the 5th vote) because the question itself *does not have the information needed to fix the issue presented* **in the question itself**.

You have a link in the question; it contains information -- the information you want us to use to solve your issue *should be in the question itself*.

Your question is being downvoted because we downvote questions that are not clear, don't show research effort, or are not useful (in fact, that's what the hover for downvoting says).

**If you'd like your question re-opened:**

Put the code you want us to help you with into the question.

**If you want your question upvoted:**

Tell us what you've tried, why it didn't work, and put some more effort into spelling, punctuation, and making the title more clear.

Comment: That clears things up. I did do the research for it, but wasn't searching for the right thing because I didn't know how to say it. I didn't include any code because I believed it wasn't entirely necessary for the question, just tossed in the codepen in case someone needed to look.

Comment: @Adjit You could have done a lot of research, but without showing us what you've tried in the question, there's no way to know if any answer will net a, "But I already tried that and it didn't work" response that just infuriates answerers because *that information should be in your question*.

Comment: Truthfully, I could've just deleted the question to avoid all of this, but thanks for clearing it up. Normally I always add code to my questions, I just felt it wasn't necessary for this question.

Comment: @Adjit It's in your best interest to fix this question and get it re-opened (and upvoted).  If you have multiple downvoted questions, there's a high-liklihood you'll be banned from asking questions by the system.

Comment: @Adjit: Just a note, I've [edited](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/23573557/revisions) the question for you :)

Comment: @AmalMurali I saw. That is very much appreciated! (i probably wouldn't have edited it...been a long day, hence my ranting) and George, if you look I maybe only have 1 or 2 downvoted questions. Like I said, normally I'm very good with it, and try not to ask too many questions.

Comment: @AmalMurali thanks to both of you. It will definitely help me for future questioning!

Answer (score 6):

> "This question appears to be off-topic because it lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem. Describe your problem in more detail or include a minimal example **in the question itself**."

Emphasis added. You need to include the information required to answer your question *in the body of the question itself*, not behind a link to another site.

We'd like your question to make sense, even after the hosting service where you posted your code goes down, or after you've fixed the problem in the source on your site. If you only posted the relevant code *somewhere else*, your question would be useless to future visitors *here* because they won't be able to see if your problem is the same thing they're experiencing.