# How can I start a discussion critiquing the culture of Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, meta

How can one ask a question that is critical of the gamification community on SO with as little offense as possible? Is it even possible?

Comment: I'd recommend not comparing closing your bad questions to the genocide of millions of people, to begin with.

Comment: "introductory question/discussion" - I kinda miss both. What did you want to discuss? All I see is a slur and no supporting evidence.

Comment: @Wooble Does the term "Soup Nazi" do the same thing? I'll change it to whatever you think is more appropriate. This has nothing to do with [any] genocide, but the colloquial use of the term for the sake of brevity. When you say it pithy, people ask for clarity, when you give clarity, they want brevity. You can't please everyone all the time... :)

Comment: Just don't use language, phrases or words that might be seen to be offensive to and by large groups of people?

Comment: What's a "Soup Nazi"? Perhaps it'd be better to skip the strange terms and just lay out what you mean. Sometimes simplicity is best, and perhaps also the most concise because you don't have to bother explaining what terms mean.

Comment: No one using the term "Soup Nazi" was trying to engage said soup maker in a constructive dialog about the reasons for his customer service policies. If that was their aim, using the term would have been a bad start.

Comment: Why bother asking how to ask? Just ask your question. The comments will let you know how/if your question could be improved.

Comment: OMG... guys, seriously. It was not the intent, directly or indirectly... (did you _really_ get that I was on about a holocaust? really??) Q: Would you like me to repost the same question again & start over?

Comment: "Soup Nazi" was a character on the old Seinfeld TV series.

Comment: No, don't repost the *same* question. Just ask the question you actually wanted to ask. No need to ask how to ask. And please make sure your question is clear from the start -- the misunderstanding is because no one could figure out what you were talking about.

Comment: @user3580294 A Soup N*zi (better?) is a character on a TV show, and a monicker attached to anyone who is so obsessed with the letter of something that the spirit of the thing suffers. My explanations will go down in flames, so this should help: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soup_nazi

Comment: @Plutonix Ah, I see. First time coming across that term, guess I have some reading to do. Thanks!

Comment: @PatTrainor Yep, figured out pretty quickly, but thanks. I really need to get out more...

Comment: @Cupcake Excellent edit. That's the way it should have been from the start.

Comment: @user3580294 no kidding `:/`

Comment: I'm all in favour of discussions about the culture of SO, but using [Godwin's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Godwin%27s_law) on the first revision, just doesn't seem the right way to do this.

Comment: @PLEASEDELETEME it seems like you need a little time to cool off from being so overly emotional. As I've already mentioned, you're welcome to start a discussion about issues with [so], but you have to do so in a way that's constructive, not provocative and inflammatory.

Comment: People love playing _games_.

Comment: @PLEASEDELETEME No soup for you!!!

Comment: And, once again, the system works as designed.

Comment: @Will (disgruntled) user deletion?

Comment: @PLEASEDELETEME `sudo rm -rf --no-preserve-root /`

Comment: You can't discuss it. I made something like 3 posts on here and I can already tell that people on meta are, in large part, awful (when compared with other SO sites/subsites). Talking about it on SO, while it would probably yield better results, is disallowed.

Comment: This post makes absolutely no sense. 1) Obviously a major chunk of the OP was removed. 2) The soup nazi was in no way 'so obsessed with the letter of something that the spirit of the thing suffers' - nor were actual Nazis. 3) Censoring the word "nazi" is completely pointless, but using it as an epithet against people on this site will earn you a great deal of dislike. How on earth can you not see the difference?

Comment: You can't and this is the nature of Nazism(and probably humans). You see the result. Same thing happened in Nazi Germany. At first, everyone said there was no problem. Then people said "Everything is great!"... then it went to "Well, things are good". The problems are just isolated random occurrence. Then things started to get better and someone said "This is starting to feel like ancient Rome!" and people said that it is offensive to compare the great Germany to rome's atrocities. And so the story guys. You can't change morons, only time can.

Comment: Just taking a look at the 18 downvotes you have, I think the answer is: "You can't make a single critic to Stack Over Flow."

Comment: I came looking for the same information.  Just look at the down-votes.  I am disgusted with the lack of willingness for feedback and suggestions to improve the experience.

Comment: @Maiya Take a look at the edit history, in particular the original text. Downvotes might have happened because of how the question was worded (calling users nazis).

Comment: @ModusTollens Hi - I looked at it. I guess I can see why some people might take offense, but I honestly don't see it as that serious. I think of it in the same terms as "The Soup Nazi" (ie just a figure of speech). People with higher skill levels should be able to laugh at themselves a little, and see that they might be acting overly zealous.  (Punching up vs. punching down).  If they can't, that might be part of the problem?

Comment: @Maiya To show you the bigger picture I'll post a link to how new users sometimes react when they don't know the site very well and feel mistreated. A post like this one might be not so bad, but taking into consideration the amount of abuse users who try to keep the site clean are exposed to, it is no wonder they don't take it lightly. These are actual reactions from new users (warning, not safe for work): https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/366733/1288408 Polite speech _is_ important. Name-calling is not a good entry point for a constructive discussion.

Comment: @ModusTollens But again, they could edit the post & tell the person *why* they are rigid about this point. Just down-voting creates more feeling of alienation. In a regular environment, being called a "soup nazi" or "code nazi" is just not that deep. Too much communication here is punitive instead of actually giving information. Also, if so many beginners feel that a lot of moderators do act like [controversial figure-of-speech] could it actually point to a valid issue? Does being a good programmer (thus able to rack in rep points) mean that you are even a barely competent communicator?

Comment: @Maiya No it can't point to a valid issue. It is deep. Using "nazi" to show how bad moderators are works both ways - it is supposed to show how badly users feel treated. But it also compares _downvotes on a website_ to the atrocities performed by a terrible regime. It is a slap in the face of victims of actual atrocities. Don't use it. Use friendly discourse instead. I have never seen a friendly post being met with aggression. We all have to work together here, users like you and me _are_ the site whether we are looking for answers or trying to keep it clean. Please assume good intentions.

Comment: @ModusTollens This is getting really too heavy for me.  You're fixating on the word "nazi" (as in "soup-nazi") when I didn't even disagree with people editing it out of the post. And your stating, categorically that a large number of beginners complaining of a certain behavior can't possibly point to a valid concern. Conversation over.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Even with the edits, this is rather unclear.

You want to ask about the culture here and how it came about?

Just ask.

Use facts and numbers. Tag with the [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) tag. Give examples.

Comment: I can tell such a discussion is unwanted to the point of angering the community. And this was just asking HOW & WHERE to ask.. Could you imagine what they'd do to me if I actually _asked_? If someone can't be constructively critical without invoking the wrath of the righteous, then only a fool would continue. I tried. I give up. You guys win.

Comment: @PatTrainor The problem wasn't the fact that you were asking how/where to ask. The problem was the manner in which you phrased the question. Questions critical of SO are perfectly acceptable here, as long as they are well-formed questions.

Comment: @PatTrainor it is OK to be critical of [so], but you must be **fair** in your criticism. Do not rant. Be open-minded, and open to having an actual discussion about issues.

Comment: And try to use neutral terminology with a constructive tone.  Calling people (or groups of people) names, whether deserved or not deserved, will usually not go well.

Comment: @user3580294 ... and not things that had been discussed ad absurdum already, if I may add.

Answer (score 41):

Adding to [Oded's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265417/456814),

1. Avoid alienating your audience.
2. Avoid name-calling.
3. Avoid invocation of [Godwin's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Godwin's_law), either directly or indirectly.

   - Quoting Wooble

     > I'd recommend not comparing closing your bad questions to the genocide of millions of people, to begin with. — [link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265415/how-can-i-start-a-discussion-critiquing-the-culture-of-stack-overflow#comment59807_265415)
     >
     > No one using the term "Soup Nazi" was trying to engage said soup maker in a constructive dialog about the reasons for his customer service policies. If that was their aim, using the term would have been a bad start. — [link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265415/how-can-i-start-a-discussion-critiquing-the-culture-of-stack-overflow#comment59814_265415)
4. Avoid inflammatory, provocative, overly-emotional, hyperbolic, and bombastic language.

   - Quoting [psubsee2003](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265415/how-can-i-start-a-discussion-critiquing-the-culture-of-stack-overflow#comment59843_265417):

     > Try to use neutral terminology with a constructive tone. Calling people (or groups of people) names, whether deserved or not deserved, will usually not go well.
5. Avoid angry rants.
6. Avoid whining.
7. Be open-minded, not close-minded.
8. Read up on the following, before you ask your question:

   - [Getting to Know Stack Overflow's Voting Culture](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251487/getting-to-know-stack-overflows-voting-culture?lq=1)
   - [Downvotes on Meta are confusing: do they *really* mean poor-post quality, or just disagreement?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254108/downvotes-on-meta-are-confusing-do-they-really-mean-poor-post-quality-or-jus/254113#254113)
   - [How do I participate in Meta and not die trying?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44188/how-do-i-participate-in-meta-and-not-die-trying) (thanks for the link Oded!)
   - [Rant tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/rant/info) on Meta Stack Exchange (thanks animuson!)

Comment: There is also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44188/how-do-i-participate-in-meta-and-not-die-trying

Comment: For what it's worth, not all Nazi comparisons are Godwin's Law invokable. The original context here was "topic nazi" which is about as offensive as "grammar nazi". No one really makes a comparison to Hitler or real Nazis when they talk about a "grammar nazi". I'm not saying it's the classiest thing to do anyway, and this whole question was doomed from the start, and personally I think the guy is trolling and isn't worth our time... but I also think the commenters are just looking for anything snarky they can at this point. "Throw the book at him" so to speak.

Comment: @corsiKa anyone coming here to Meta to start a critical discussion should just avoid using the word "Nazi", period, no matter how they intended to use it. Same goes for related terms like "fascist", etc. All of those things carry a boat-load of negative connotations, and are completely hyperbolic and unnecessary. They derail constructive discussions too easily, as I think you've already seen.

Comment: Exactly. The reactions are hyperbolic and unnecessary. And you used one of those hyperbolic and unnecessary reactions to support your suggestion not to do it as though it was rational and warranted.

Comment: @corsiKa agree to disagree? `:P`

Comment: You... you... *Cupcake!*

Comment: @AndrewBarber "Cupcake's Law": *the tendency of online discussions to devolve into hilarity when every instance of the invocation of Godwin's Law is replaced by cupcakes*.

Comment: Cupcake's Law seems much more fun than Godwin's!

Comment: @Oded I think even better MSE reference (cross-site dupe) is [Is it possible on MSE to question something that people hold dear without getting “disagreement downvoted”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/208876/165773)

Answer (score 17):

It is perhaps worth adding that we understand that what we have here is truly amazing: a vast concentration of programing experts (and near experts and adequate practitioners and beginners) who are all willing to share of their knowledge for no reward but a warm fuzzy feeling and some worthless internet points.

We understand that you would like to tap that reservoir in various ways. We get it.

What we would like you to get it that this accumulation of interest and good will did not happen by accident. It was sowed and sprouted by the efforts of some widely regarded programming bloggers and business people and has been tended and trimmed and cared for by many people (both employees and users) who care about it.

These rules are not (at least in our minds) arbitrary: they are the result of careful observation and some hard fought, difficult decisions.

You are going to have to show us why we should change our minds. Not why ***you*** want a change, but why ***the community wants*** a change. What is in it for us?

This can be done, but it is not easy.

Comment: This is a good answer, but unfortunately I doubt that the original poster will ever receive it `:/`

Comment: This is one of the best replies to the question-rant "why does SO hate me" that I have read!

Comment: From my experience, I think you* are shutting out people who are trying to enter the community, in the first place.  I put forward that "regarded programming bloggers" still have blind spots;  and that it is likely that they could have the same blind spots.  If beginners are slapped down and shut out before they even have a chance to become a part of the community, then you will never receive their feedback, in the first place.  *(not you specifically, but the policies/culture).

Comment: @Maiya Beginners are not slapped down and shut out, but some beginners don't come to meta with an open mind and polite speech, unfortunately. The question on this thread was one of those until it was edited.

Comment: @ModusTollens That is not the experience that I had coming to the site as a beginner, and I know a lot of hard working beginners in real life that share the frustration. From what I have seen/experienced, the lack of knowledge at a beginner level is often down-voted, instead of giving the person feedback about what it is that they are missing. Often the comments on beginner posts are arrogant and dismissive, as if the person is intentionally being "lazy" - instead of realizing that they may not have formal training and may be confused about where and how to start.

Comment: @Maiya When you see comments like that, please flag them immediately as "rude". Such behavior is not ok. We have a "be nice" policy, so feel free to flag.

Comment: @ModusTollens Thanks, I do sometimes. But is often just harsh attitude of dismissiveness & being arrogantly obtuse about helping some see see what they are missing. & it is often rooted in arguments that are literally the rules of SO. Also, if u get something TOTALLY wrong, but ur code happens to have recursion in it, then the rude ppl leave u alone. But, if u have a lack of understanding that is a basic or novice level, u r penalized w/ unexplained down-vote &/or dismissive comment. Thus it seems like beginners are not welcome or understood. Also, once you edit, people don't fix their votes.