# Can we update the "rant" close reason to link to how to *constructively* conduct criticisms of Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, meta

Unconstructive rants from disgruntled users are not uncommon on Meta. There were two of them from the same user about half an hour ago. Those that don't end up being closed as duplicate of [Why is Stack Overflow so negative of late?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251758/why-is-stack-overflow-so-negative-of-late) end up being closed with:

> This question **does not appear to seek input and discussion** from
>   the community. If you have encountered a problem on one of our sites,
>   please describe it in detail. See also: [What is "meta"? How does it
>   work?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta)

Maybe it's just me, but isn't "does not appear to seek input and discussion" awfully vague? The linked Help Center page on Meta doesn't really explain how to constructively approach criticisms of Stack Overflow and Meta either.

#### Providing better discussion tips to misguided, disgruntled users

I think it would be really helpful for ranting users if we could point out to them how they can actually have a productive discussion on Meta. We certainly have a lot of really great tips:

1. [How can I start a discussion critiquing the culture of Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265415/how-can-i-start-a-discussion-critiquing-the-culture-of-stack-overflow/265419#265419)
2. [How do I participate in Meta and not die trying?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44188/how-do-i-participate-in-meta-and-not-die-trying/44189#44189)

I think it would be really great if we could have the close reason link directly to one of those (I suppose we might have to clean up #1 first though), like

> This question **does not appear to seek input and discussion** from
>   the community. If you have encountered a problem on one of our sites,
>   please describe it in detail. See also: [What is "meta"? How does it
>   work?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta) and [How can I start a discussion critiquing the culture of Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265415/how-can-i-start-a-discussion-critiquing-the-culture-of-stack-overflow/265419#265419)

That way, it's more direct and harder to miss. Another alternative is to have the Help Center page link to it, but that requires 2 clicks instead of 1, and my guess is that ranting users are less likely to read through an entire Help Center page looking for a link to where to find tips for how to *constructively* criticize Stack Overflow. Why not just put the link right in their faces to begin with?

#### Another angle

This guy originally [thought he was writing an angry rant](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254770/what-is-stack-overflow-s-goal/254773#comment20690_254770), and it ended up turning into one of the [most productive discussions on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254770/456814). How can we encourage more people to write more like him?

Thoughts?

Comment: I've wanted to re-write those to be honest. We just copy-pasted them from Meta SE to *have* some better close reasons for off-topic.

Comment: @animuson rewrite the close reasons, or the posts? Copy-pasted the close reasons?

Comment: The close reasons. I really don't like how either one of them is phrased.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi it was definitely warranted, I'm not saying that it wasn't. I'm just saying that, since apparently he didn't get the hint the first time, maybe we can do a better job of pointing out how one can actually start a constructive conversation here. This one disgruntled user is certainly *not* going to be the last.

Comment: Your proposed text is far better than the current close reason. Rants are unfortunately very frequent.

Comment: ... but they are disgruntled/angry. Do you have any real hope that they'll go "ah, so that's how I phrase constructively how miserable this hell hole is with its bastard coated bastards with bastard filling"?

Comment: @Bart who knows, maybe it will be a wake up call for someone. At least no one will be able to say that we didn't try to show them how to do it right.

Comment: Never knew you could get Cupcake with bastard filling.