# Is "does not appear to seek input and discussion" applicable because of comments?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, meta

As we all know comments are sometimes used for extended discussions on meta and sometimes it gets heated, because OP and commenter won't agree. Can such discussion be a reason to close a Meta question as "does not appear to seek input and discussion", if it doesn't have other flaws?

The [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) explains that such discussions shouldn't be started at all in comments. Therefore wouldn't it be better to clean up the comments and apply close reasons only based on the question itself?

Comment: Related but not about comments specifically: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268226

Comment: The help center applies to SO, not meta.  A [discussion] is often conducted in comments since the normal Q+A format does not accommodate the normal back-and-forth that characterizes people discussing something.  It very rarely gets out of hand, not agreeing is entirely normal.

Comment: @HansPassant: Thanks. That answers the second part: comments shouldn't been clean up on Meta.

Comment: Well, comments should be cleaned up even on meta. But the threshold is far higher, many reasons being far less applicable. An obsolete comment is still obsolete after integration into the question, though leave it if removing damages parts of the discussion which should stay.

Answer (score 3):

> Can heated comments be an acceptable reason to close as "not seeking input and discussion"?

In and of themselves, no.
They can be an indication that one side or the other is in a state of denial though, which *might* conceivably justify it.
Deciding whether it does is a judgement call, and better to err on the side of not closing (Imho, used too much in those cases), or at least not closing *yet*.

Also, extra care has to be taken not to close migrated questions wrongly, as long as that rejects the migration, see my feature-request [Don't treat closed questions on meta as rejected migrations from main](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/299599).