# Why was my question deleted after posting the following META question 10 minutes ago?

Tags: discussion

So I posted a question in **May 14th** (over 3 months ago), which, as of literally 8 minutes ago, had received 3 downvotes. Most of these downvotes were from May. Here used to be the question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23664236/this-code-breaks-with-nullreferenceexception

So I posted a question 8 minutes ago in Meta asking why it had received **3 downvotes**. Two members made good observations. This is the meta question: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270086/why-3-downvotes-for-this-question

Now I look at the previous SO question, and it received 3 more downvotes and was then deleted. In other words, in the last 8 minutes a question 3 months old received 3 more downvotes and was deleted. And my meta question received 7 downvotes.

Out of curiosity, how come?

Comment: That would be called the [Meta Effect](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22meta+effect%22). You drew attention to the question on Meta and users with the privileges to delete voted to delete your question.

Comment: Sometimes we should keep the skeletons in the closet...

Comment: I just enjoy asking. I love it how hateful people just downvote for no reason. I think that's my other meta question.

Comment: @user3605366 They didn't downvote for no reason. They downvoted for very good reasons.  They even told you what those reasons were.  Ignoring those reasons and pretending that it is done out of hate, when it very obviously is not, is unconstructive, unhelpful, and will prevent you from improving in response to the valuable feedback you've been given.

Comment: Be happy we deleted it before it could accumulate more downvotes.

Comment: [STRONGLY RELATED](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269191/impose-a-24-hour-voting-freeze-on-questions-being-discussed-on-meta/269274#269274)

Comment: @AnthonyPegram: The harm is already done. Plus, it was a helpful question to me.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram, as I mentioned, the 3 downvotes from May were reasonable. But were the 3 downvotes in the last 10 minutes really necessary?

Comment: `"it was a helpful question to me"` but it wasn't useful to the community as a whole.

Answer (score 16):

What you are seeing is an example of the ["Meta Effect"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251487/getting-to-know-stack-overflows-voting-culture).

By linking to a question on the main site here you are bringing it to the attention of people who are more than averagely concerned with the state of the site. This means that if there is *anything* wrong with your post then it's going to be highlighted and subject to more intense scrutiny than would otherwise be the case.

Comment: But delete it? Really?

Comment: @user3605366 In what way was that post adding value to the programming community?  How is the world better for having that post around?

Comment: So you didn't think my question added any value?

Comment: @user3605366 I do not.  Why do you think it does?  Who's going to find the question, how is it going to help them, how would the 10,000 other NRE questions out there not provide the same, if not a far better, level of help?

Comment: Do you wanna bet some of your SO reputation that if I post another meta question with a link to another question of mine with no downvotes, I'll get at least 5 downvotes in less than 5 minutes?

Comment: @user3605366 If you have another bad question, it will surely be downvoted. That's how it works.

Comment: @user3605366 Having taken a glance at several of your 0 scored questions, most of them look pretty bad and should have gotten downvotes but didn't due to a lack of attention, so I most certainly wouldn't take that bet.  If you asked better questions, then I'd take that bet right away.

Comment: @Servy, I see you also downvoted several my other questions. They were pretty bad also, huh? I expect nothing less.

Comment: @user3605366 Voting is anonymous.

Comment: @user3605366 No, actually, I didn't.  I suppose I should have, but I felt enough pity for you that I didn't.  You're going a good job of convincing me that that was a mistake.

Comment: @Servy, Gee, thanks for feeling pity; that's important to me. Honestly, I enjoy asking these questions and seeing spite disguised as a 'Meta Effect'. Go ahead and downvote away.

Comment: @Servy, Btw, did you actually think that I wasn't expecting all this retribution from posting this question? C'mon.

Comment: @user3605366 Assuming that anyone who disagrees with you only acts out of spite, that they are always wrong, know that they are wrong, and feel that punishing you is all that matters to them is simply unhealthy.

Comment: @user3605366 I think that you're being intentionally disruptive because you like the attention that you're getting, which is why you're being intentionally unconstructive, abrasive, trying to pick fights, and appear to have no interest whatsoever in actually improving or contributing to the community in a positive way.  The common slang term for such behavior in this context would be trolling.

Answer (score 9):

Because you drew attention to it.

Comment: So if I draw attention to it, it's downvoted? I did not know that.

Comment: @user3605366: if the question is, in the view of the majority of users, downvote worthy then attracting meta attention to it can draw more downvotes, yes.

Comment: @user3605366: if you draw attention and it is not a pristine question, yes it'll attract negative attention.

Comment: @user3605366: That's too sloppy. More precisely, it's like this: If it's a bad question, people who see it will downvote it. If you post on meta, more people will see it.

Comment: @user3605366: the inverse is also true; a good high quality post getting attention from Meta can also draw upvotes.

Comment: So what's wrong with my previous meta question?

Comment: @user3605366 When you draw attention to a post people will do whatever they would have done had they found the post naturally.  By artificially increasing the view count, you artificially increase the number of all sorts of user actions on that post.

Comment: @user3605366: nothing is wrong per se with you meta question. People passing through meta SO will see your other question though, and then they will act on it

Comment: @user3605366 I know I can say that I downvoted the meta post because you were asking us why your question was downvoted *when the original question was full of comments explaining why people felt it wasn't a good question*.  This gives the impression that you didn't even bother to read the comments on your own question before asking others for more feedback.

Comment: @user3605366 It's interesting that you come and ask everyone for a feedback on why your question was downvoted. When you get opinions that differ from yours, you just ignore them. If you have your own opinion and isn't open for other opinions, just don't ask.

Comment: @MelanciaUK, were you able to read my SO question? I forgot, they deleted it. Is this the **Copy What Everyone Says** effect?

Comment: @Servy, understood. So you downvoted the SO question because you didn't like my meta question to a link to another meta question and an SO question?

Comment: @user3605366 I'm not pointing out your question. I'm pointing out that anyone looking for someone else's opinion, should be aware to the fact that those opinions can differ. To keep moaning about that on every question/answer/comment is just a proof that you're not up to discuss anything. You have your own opinion and that's your absolute truth.

Comment: @user3605366 No, I downvoted the SO question because it's a low quality question that doesn't demonstrate research or debugging effort in which you simply tried to get other people to debug your program for you so that you wouldn't need to bother.

Comment: @MelanciaUK, do you think I'm moaning? I think you should get the **Copy What Everyone Says** badge.

Comment: @Servy, that's your opinion, and unfortunately, it's what I expected.

Comment: @user3605366 Checking your last questions posted here, yes, you're moaning. About one question downvoted, then the question deleted, then about your account being blocked...

Comment: @user3605366 yes, that is my opinion, and I used the appropriate tools to express that opinion.  I'd be disappointed in you if you *didn't* expect me to downvote a post that I felt was of low quality and didn't meet the standards of the site.  Why would anyone expect otherwise?

Comment: @user3605366 by the way with a certain rep, you can see deleted questions, so yes maybe Melancia saw it (I am FAR from sure, but 5K seems like around what you need to see that).

Comment: @Julldar [You need 10k rep to see deleted questions.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools)

Comment: @Servy  thanx for the clarification, I'm never clear on all these limits and I rarely bother to go see the rep threshold ^^

Comment: @Julldar I couldn't see the question _in question_, that's why I made it clear to the OP that my opinions here are just related to their behavior when getting the feedback that they actually asked for.

Comment: @MelanciaUK yeah I see now that with 10K being the needed rep you couldn't have seen it :P.  Sorry for the assumption.  But yes, I am totally on board with you... when you request for feedback (especially on internet) expect some people to disagree with you...

Comment: MelanciaUK has 5,297 points. That's why he should get the **Copy What Everyone Says** badge. It fits him to a T.

Comment: @user3605366 if you tried being a bit more positive maybe you wouldn't have this big an issue with SO.... I have pretty much the same amount of rep as you, and honestly, I can understand why a question with "why is MY code not working" will be deleted if enough attention is brought to it. It's disappointing for you I can understand that, but when people come back with comments about your question, consider editing it and taking it in stride.  Will only make you a better SO user, and will help with that resentment over every single downvote you seem to have