# Is it appropriate to ask for an answer to be reviewed on Meta Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, support, answers

Today, I spotted a highly upvoted answer from a four year old question which is factually incorrect. Not only wrong, but misleading to future visitors. Also (without a selected answer), as the most recently active answer it sits right at the top of answers some visitors will see.

I downvoted it, left a comment (there was already a highly voted comment which agreed with my observations), and usually that would be it. But I checked the upvote to down-vote ratio and almost no-one has downvoted. Usually, the procedure would be to leave the answer to get downvoted naturally by future visitors so that it is shown to be a bad answer. But after 2 years, that has not happened.

I thought about flagging it for requiring moderator attention, but it doesn't break any rules by being incorrect and there is very little a single moderator could do in this context. So my question is, is it appropriate to ask for the answer to be reviewed by the Meta community?

- [Answer in question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12051075/2182928)

Comment: **Neither moderators nor the Meta community review answers for *factual correctness*.** You've done what you (and anyone else) can do: downvoted and left a comment. The only other option is to edit the answer, but that works best if there is just a minor error or a simple omission. If it's fundamentally wrong, editing just confuses things.

Comment: No worries, that answer is competing with no one less than... yep, the man himself!

Comment: Now that's you've seen concrete evidence that a *lot* of people can be drastically wrong, how can you propose to gather a posse to tar-and-feather a post?  What if they're wrong?

Comment: The default sort order is votes not active anyway AFAIK. And even if people do have it ordered by active then downvoting the answer won't prevent it being shown at the top.

Comment: @HansPassant - That, is a very good point.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [What's Meta?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta):

> Meta is for:
>
> - asking questions about how the websites work
> - asking questions of the community
> - posting bugs
> - suggesting improvements
> - proposing new features

So, no: this is not the place to discuss the technical accuracy of answers, but you will probably notice that some action will be taken on that answer via the [Meta effect](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251487/getting-to-know-stack-overflows-voting-culture).

Moderators will decline any flags asking for a review of technical accuracy, because that is not what they're here for.

---

However, to address your question: I don't think you have much to worry about. By default, answers are sorted by votes, not activity, so most users will see the top answer, which is much more highly voted than the one in question.

Also (and probably more importantly), the answer is competing with [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet)'s answer. Jon Skeet [is Stack Overflow royalty](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19499/258672): he has the highest reputation of any user and almost certainly will for quite a long time, so anyone who has been here for a while would recognize that his answers are pretty credible.

Comment: Using the term "competing" loosely ;-) The difference in votes between Skeet's and the next (under discussion) answer is more than 3 times my own top-voted answer.

Comment: @Jongware The difference is almost *14 times* more than mine.