# Strange Downvoting of my Valid Answer (Maybe?)

Tags: discussion, answers, downvotes, answer-quality

I recently answered a SO question here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26481798/how-to-show-pixel-value-in-a-label-in-c/26481920#26481920

My answer is accurate, I was the first to answer, I answered the question as it was asked, and I updated my answer with more detail as the OP added to the conversation via comments.

A few minutes later, I noticed that I had a -4 in my activity feed, and my answer now has a rating of -2. This downvoting came out of nowhere about 10 minutes after I posted my answer. None before, and none since.

This is probably all valid activity, but to date I have not seen activity like this on my answers. Especially more than a single downvote on an answer that is clearly on point. There is another answer in the thread that is arguably better, but would that justify mine being buried?

I'm not that concerned about it; I can certainly put on my big-boy pants and brush off a measly -4, but I'm mostly posting because I've never actually seen this happen before and was wondering if this is typical and I've mainly just avoided it until now.

Comment: Obviously someone, for some reason (Or none at all), dislikes your answer. There's nothing we can really do about it.

Comment: Prepare yourself for the [meta effect](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251487/getting-to-know-stack-overflows-voting-culture/251488#251488).. be it good, or bad.

Comment: @Cerbrus I figured that might be the case. I was kind of hoping the r*ddit mentality would stay away from SO. :)

Comment: I can't judge the validity of the answer nor the intentions of the downvoters, but perhaps they disliked your phrasing "does this work?", suggesting that you aren't confident of your answer and/or haven't tried.

Comment: @Pekka웃 There's a comment now on that answer indicating that someone read the answer as "not an answer".

Comment: @Pekka웃 Good point! I'll try to avoid such verbiage in the future. I answered that way because I was replying on my phone and couldn't test the answer at that very moment.

Comment: The OP clearly doesn't understand the Color struct and you provided no explanation, just a little code.  I'm not pretending to understand the downvoters, just guessing, but your answer is not all that good.  Compare yours to the other.  The Author of that answer used roughly the same code, but provided an explanation of what `Color` is.  Also you left off tje 4th component of the Color... the Alpha channel.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Thanks for the reply. The Alpha channel isn't required--I'm just outputting a string, so the code should be valid as is. Taking a pixel sample on screen arguably wouldn't need Alpha. Agreed that my answer could be more verbose!

Comment: @trnelson I'm just theorizing on possible explanations.  The lack of any explanation at all is what hurts the answer in my eyes.  I certainly would have hoped that someone wouldn't have downvoted simply because you ignored the Alpha.

Comment: Looks like you got hit by roboreviewers.  Nothing we can do about the downvotes, but I've flagged and pointed out some folks need a temporary review ban.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Going on the comments below your answer, it is likely someone flagged your answer as Not An Answer (NAA). This explains the downvotes too.

A cause for this might be the way you formulated your answer. Generally it is best to stay away from posing questions in an answer, since they might be confused by 'another question'.

So instead of 'Does this work?', use something like 'If ..., you should try ...'.

Comment: Well put, and thanks for the response. Still finding my footing here on SO a little, and I can definitely see how my wording could be a turn off.

Comment: @trnelson I think otherwise your answer is the same as the other one, but I would still not upvote it, due to you answering a poorly researched question. See how many close votes there are already.

Comment: @simonzack: You should judge the answer, not the question. Vote to close / downvote the question for being off-topic.

Comment: @PatrickHofman That's why I do not downvote the answer, but I would not upvote it either to encourage more people asking poorly researched questions.

Comment: @simonzack: Okay, but *excellent* answers to poor questions are possible. In this case I indeed wouldn't upvote too.