# Is there a way to "donate" reputation?

Tags: discussion

Today I asked a question on askUbuntu and a very friendly person edited my question. And I have to admit: the question was really improved by this edit.

I know that the editor receives two points for his work but in that situation I was so delighted that I thought to myself: "if there would be a 'donate like' button I would take 5 points of my reputation and give it to that person".

So, is there such a feature? If not, is that for a very specific reason or would this be worth a "new feature request"?

Comment: ..and if so, can the donation be negative?

Comment: There is the bounty system.  Of course this applies only to answers.  So in your edit situation bounties don't work.

Comment: There was a duplicate question somewhere but I can't find it now. I think the main reason was that with such a system the reputation would become like currency to buy or sell. People with high reputation would also the able to boost up other people for no reason.. and other stuff.

Comment: Related: [Meta: Donate reputation?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77444/donate-reputation)

Comment: @Spokey But I think that could be solved technically; for example to only allow donations as "reaction" to something that affected me: somebody giving a **super** answer; somebody editing, commenting my question, answer. Then put in restrictions (like max. 1 donation per day, max donation 10 points, no repeated donations to the same person, ...). I think that a few simple rules would eliminate 99% of all potential "misuse" cases.

Comment: Talking about negative donations: any explanations on the downvotes for this question are highly welcome.

Comment: @Jägermeister downvotes on meta also indicate disagreement.  Not just the state of the post.  [One explanation for voting culture](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251487/getting-to-know-stack-overflows-voting-culture/251488#251488)

Comment: @Jägermeister technically it's most likely wanted but it's not what reputation is supposed to be. If you think an answer is great you can show your appreciation by simply up-voting it. Reputation is also highly tied to the trust and privileges a user gets on the site. The amount a user gets from answering and asking questions is just about right for the progress. Other issues show up when new users will ask question, think they won't ever ask again and just give their earned reputation from that question to the person who answers it. All in all it requires too many rules and too big of a 1/2

Comment: change to the system and the user mentality to implement this. Like I said, if you think an answer is great just up-vote it. It time as more people find it will will stack up more votes 2/2

Comment: Nope. Noooooopenopenope nope nope nope. Nope. Nope nope. Nope.

Comment: @JackManey - you disagree with the proposal, then?

Comment: Go to his profile and upvote one of his answers. Just one; don't do multiple as this will be considered like serial voting (and be reversed by the system, in addition to looking bad).

Comment: I actually like this suggestion. There are times when a particular person 'saves the day' and I honestly would donate 25 rep points of mine. I always think, "thank you, thank you, thank you and want to upvote multiple times"

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No, that isn't really possible.  The only feature that comes remotely close is the "Reward an existing answer" option for assigning a bounty to a question.  But that is of course not close to a good edit.  And it is really rather important that it is an excellent answer.  As-is, this feature does get abused, one friend passing rep to another.  Not the kind of impression you want to make :)

Consider this a random act of kindness from a complete stranger.  It happens thousands of times every day on these sites and they expect nothing in return.