# Instead of a "thanks" button, why not a "give rep" button?

Tags: discussion

[I am aware that this has been asked before but it was half a decade ago and we don't have any way to "bump" meta posts, so.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289780/is-there-a-way-to-donate-reputation)

The thanks button came and, deservedly, went rather quickly afterwards. The rationale for its quick death was sound: upvotes indicate assent.

But sometimes, you've been struggling with something for a whole day, or a *whole damn week*, and you try a specific combination of Google-fu and find an answer you didn't before, or an answer you've already come across is suddenly relevant to where you are in your problem-solving...

... and that answer immediately solves the issue that's been causing you to bang your head against the wall. You sigh with relief, and sit back and finally relax, and generally just feel so much better that you feel downright charitable. You'd like to do something nice for that person who posted that answer, and a single lousy upvote really doesn't seem like enough.

You've got rep, because you participate on Stack Overflow. And right now, you can't think of a better use for that rep than to give some of it to that kind person who just saved your sanity. You'd like to slice a bit of your rep off and donate it to their answer, because they deserve it, dang nab it.

But you can't, because that feature doesn't exist. So instead you make a Meta post suggesting it for consideration, and wait for people to tell you why it's the worst idea in the history of mankind...

Comment: You can create a bounty to be awarded to an existing Answer.

Comment: I agree. I regularly catch myself going to someone's profile and upvoting their most popular answer (or question since the 5 -> 10 rep reward change) to thank them for something like a good edit or comment that can't be rewarded otherwise.

Comment: *"I regularly catch myself going to someone's profile and upvoting their most popular answer "* That isn't what votes are for though @leonheess ; you should be rewarding (upvoting) the answer/question because it has been useful to you, not because a different action the OP took deserves reward.

Comment: @Larnu I wholeheartedly agree. But it's any port in a storm, right?

Comment: @leonheess no. There's a bounty system for a reason; so that you can add additional reward to that answer. Just like chain downvotes are reversed, so too are chain upvotes. If you really want to reward someone, a bounty is by far the best way; as CertainPerformance shows in their [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/402602/2029983).

Comment: I like the idea of a bounty, but what if this user has 60 reputation or something less? Then they can't award bountie, what do they do?

Comment: @10Rep: the same thing as when they desparately want to comment but can't because of not enough rep: leave it until they can.

Comment: That all discussion focuses on an answer (don't know if that's intended by the OP or not). What if it's an edit we're talking about (as in the linked older question)? No option for a bounty here...

Comment: People already get awarded reputation for making an edit and is accepted by the view queue, @Tomerikoo .

Comment: @Larnu yes I'm aware, I'm talking about a situation as described in the link where you want to "award" more. Again, don't know if the current question focuses on answers on purpose or that's just brought as an example

Comment: "..and wait for people to tell you why it's the worst idea in the history of mankind..." :D Not much faith in meta or yourself, huh? :)

Comment: @Tomerikoo There is room for abuse in that. For instance, person one could edit person 2's post. Then person 2 could award more rep to person 1, so its not really a good idea.

Comment: @10Rep from what I understood at least, that's exactly the point of the question... At least the one in the link talks exactly about such case. When asker `x` is grateful for an edit to his own question by editor `y`. So `x` wants to "award" `y` with some extra rep to show appreciation.

Comment: @Larnu One upvote is not a chain and none of them have ever been reverted. As long as there is no other way of rewarding an edit, a comment et cetera, people will fall back to doing this. The only thing that can be done to prevent this behavior is implementing a better alternative.

Comment: when you upvote you give a 10 rep and you send the user with some calm to his gild medal, if yu want to give a bounty-

Comment: @Tomerikoo I think allowing rewards for edits will cause problems that allowing an instant reward for answers won't but I don't actually have enough room in a comment to explain and it wouldn't make sense to post this in an answer since the question isn't about edits. If you're interested, I could explain in chat.

Comment: @leonheess I've always suspected people do that (upvote an unrelated answer), because some of my top voted answers seem to get upvotes out of the blue out of proportion to how useful I'd guess they were.  Thanks for admitting it!

Comment: @BSMP I would be interested to hear if you can open up a chat. I don't know if that's possible

Comment: @usr2564301 "leave it until they can" - Sadly, no. I've seen a lot of answers that should be comments. I wouldn't expect it to be different with bounties.

Comment: @Tomerikoo [Discussion about awarding extra reputation for edits](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224010/discussion-about-awarding-extra-reputation-for-edits) - possibly I'm being a worry wart but there it is.

Comment: No, reputation should not become a form of currency or a reward system.

Comment: @Gimby the reputation is a reward system though.

Answer (score 32):

Such a feature does exist. They're called [bounties](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty).

> A bounty is a special reputation award given to answers. It is funded by the personal reputation of the user who offers it, and is non-refundable. If you see a question that has not gotten a satisfactory answer, a bounty may help attract more attention and more answers. Slice off anywhere from +50 to +500 of your own hard-earned reputation, and attach it to any question as a bounty. You do not need to be the asker of the question to offer a bounty on it.

You can use bounties not only to draw more attention to a question which hasn't received an adequate response, but you can also use a bounty to reward an existing answer.

For example, that's what's happening with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27733731/passing-requirechromedriver-path-directly-to-selenium-webdriver):

> The bounty expires in 3 days. Answers to this question are eligible for a +250 reputation bounty. KyleMit wants to reward an existing answer:

> > Thanks jt000! Appreciate the answer - here's some rep :)

Comment: All true, but I assume the OP has something in mind which would take effect immediately, like an upvote does.  The bounty you linked to was started 4 days ago, but it has not been awarded yet.   The bounty doc says minimum of 1 day.  Does that mean the bounty starter could have awarded it by now?  Can you update your Answer with comments regarding the time associated with bounties?

Comment: That is exactly what suggested in answer linked by OP... While I totally agree with this answer in general, I don't see how it actually can answer this question...

Comment: _"Such a feature does exist. They're called bounties."_ -- sort of. Bounties are a way to accomplish the desired effect, but not a perfect one and not without drawbacks. See e.g. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297338/maybe-add-posibility-to-just-pass-fast-bounty-to-other-post-to-show-your-gra. That said, there are unintended consequences that streamlining the bounty system to achieve some _different_ goal than was originally conceived would cause. See e.g. [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297356) to previously-mentioned question.

Comment: teehee - [30k worth of thanks so far](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1366033/kylemit?tab=bounties&sort=offered)  :)

Comment: The best part of awarding a useful answer with a bounty is that you draw additional attention to it which can result in additional votes and bounties. It's like one of those "matching gift" pledge drives that double your impact.

Answer (score 10):

> wait for people to tell you why it's the worst idea in the history of mankind

Uh, okay…if that's what you really want?

Seriously though, I don't believe this is a good idea. The existing bounty system comes the closest, and [there has already been](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297338/maybe-add-posibility-to-just-pass-fast-bounty-to-other-post-to-show-your-gra) (a tiny amount of) discussion regarding streamlining the system to allow for this kind of transactional approach. But there's also [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297356) that points out some of the unintended consequences that argue against such a change.

And those reasons apply more generally to the idea of just being able to hand reputation over to someone willy-nilly. The idea may come from a generous, caring place. But there are already people who engage in sock-puppetry and other under-handed activities in order to improve the quantity of their holdings of fake Internet points. Being able to transfer reputation points arbitrarily from one user to another would just exacerbate the situation.

At the end of the day, the reputation points aren't very meaningful in small amounts. Just as we often have to put up with revenge downvoting, even such voting that results in actual *deletion* of posts and removal of dozens of reputation points in one swell foop, we also need to put up with the fact that we can't toss a few points here or there over to a person who might actually deserve it but outside of the usual mechanisms of the site. Ultimately, it's just all noise anyway.

Just post a short, thoughtful comment providing thanks. Knowing, of course, that comments are ephemeral, and so even that won't last very long. But at least it's something. It should provide at least as much emotional benefit as any form of currency would anyway.

Comment: As for the sock puppets, some of that could be stopped by a script that looks at how much RP are funneled to or through accounts. Sure, it won't stop it all, but it could make it difficult to be useful in any meaningful way. Also, it could be set up that there is only predefined amounts of RP to give. Combine that with the script, finding when accounts go over a certain RP a day, week, or month could be a way to spot sock puppets.