# Is there a way to get the downvotes removed

Tags: support, downvotes, downvote-reason

I was looking through some questions I asked and some of the questions are getting downvoted for no real reason. For example, I was asking about Java's timing methods and it got downvoted for no reason; my question was clear and my example shows the code in question.

Is there a way to get the downvotes removed, or have someone look into the votes to see if they are warranted?

Comment: 'I was looking through some questions I asked and some of the questions are getting downvoted for no real reason'.  This again.  Evidence please.

Comment: None of your questions are particularly heavily downvoted. I see two with 1 each. Is there one in particular that you are referring to?

Comment: @CollinD i know they aren't but if you add up the total negative votes the rep I've lost is enough to stop me for commenting on other posts.

Comment: @MartinJames the question isn't a duplicate question. The question is clear and i feel like my explaniation was to a good standard. just feels like it was down-voted for the sake of down-voting

Comment: It happens. I'd suggest really reviewing your questions and seeing how you can improve them. If you consistently get downvotes and are not being serial-targeted (which will be undone anyway) then it's probably time to look inside rather than out. Really Ed's answer pretty much sums it up.

Comment: @KyleBurns it might feel like that, but it's more likely that the downvoters found some issue with your question/s.  For instance, what do you expect SO contributors to do with your corrupted zip file?  Either you get another copy, restore from backups or you take the loss.  Data compression removes redundancy and, if there is a bit of corruption, you lose the lot.

Comment: @MartinJames The question was how to get a currupt file out of a zip file to try and recover infomation. I know the risks of data lost and I have back-ups but I was asking for the sake of other who might not have had a back-up. and the issue was that the zip files was not allowing me to remove the currupt file which could be repaired if it I could remove the file from the zip.

Comment: @KyleBurns The corrupted zip file question does not even belong on [so]. It should be OK on [su]. Whether it can be answered is a different question.

Comment: @DavidPostill I shall try and get it migrated :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No.

They're not your votes; they belong to the people who cast them, and those users were entitled to vote however they want. We only invalidate votes if they are fraudulent (such as from a [sockpuppet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sockpuppet_(Internet))) or targeted (one user voting for or against another user's posts because of the author, not the posts' content). Neither of those is relevant to your situation.

Downvotes happen. Sometimes they happen for good reasons, sometimes for bad reasons, and sometimes for no reason at all. Learn from them if you can; ignore them and move on if you can't.

That said, you will get fewer downvotes if you improve your posts. I don't want to link to any here because I don't want to trigger the ["Meta effect"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251488/2057919), but suffice it to say that some of them that have downvotes need to be improved.

Some tips (some taken from the [How to Ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which you may want to review):

- Try to write in complete, clear sentences.
- Provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).
- Pretend you're talking to a busy colleague.
- Spelling, grammar, and punctuation are important!

Comment: I'll read the review page, but you haven't really answered my question. thanks for the tips though :)

Comment: @KyleBurns I did answer your question: No, you cannot get votes on your posts removed, and no, there is nothing going on with your posts that indicates a problem justifying invalidation of any votes.

Comment: @kyleburns the FULL answer to your whole post is succintly put in the first word of this answer: "no". What more do you want as an answer? Can't be done, can't be done.

Comment: It was before an edit. I felt it was aimed towards the duplicate question(Is there any way to know who downvoted an answer) rather than mine which was is it possible to have down-votes removed. sorry if the comment was miss leading.