# Add ability to accept own answer for clarity, but give points for accepted answer to another user

Tags: discussion, feature-request, accepted-answer

Sometimes, when you ask a question, you get a very helpful answer that is not quite right, or needs some help. Because of them, you are able to craft a better response to your own problem.

Of course, your own solution is a precise solution to the problem described. While, for clarity to future seekers of knowledge, it would make sense to mark your own solution as the accepted answer, you also feel the user with the helpful user should get the points.

Could we facilitate this? Perhaps, upon accepting your own answer, your are prompted with a 'would you like to reward another answer that helped you finding the solution?'? (Rough idea, but it's the concept that matters, not so much the implementation, which is up for debate.)

The closest I can think of is editing their answer, but sometimes the edit would be so extensive as to essentially be a rewrite of their answer, so that doesn't feel like quite an appropriate usage of that tool.

This question arose from observing someone else select their own answer after broadly plagiarizing from another user, while giving them lip service credit...

Comment: Upvote the other answer. That gives 10 rep.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Or just don't, considering it apparently has problems that keep it from actually being a correct answer to the question.  If it needs to be entirely re-written in order to be a quality answer, it would seem that it has some very serious problems.

Comment: @Servy Sure, although if it helped the OP get to the solution, it is "useful" to that extent.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan If it's not a correct answer that is not going to answer the question for someone coming to this question to find an answer, then it's not "useful" to that extent, and you shouldn't be indicating that it is.

Comment: You can't argue about the usefulness of some other answer in a theoretical, abstract scenario. It may be incredibly useful, but just slightly off on implementation details. "Very serious problems" is too much to imply.

Comment: @KyleBaker When you yourself stated that it required an entire re-write of the answer in order for it to become a correct answer, "very serious problems" sure doesn't sound like too much to imply (note I didn't imply it, I stated it explicitly, or did you mean infer?).  If there is just a minor problem that doesn't require significant changes to address the problems, then it is apparently a very different situation than what you described in the question.

Comment: @Servy, still theoretically speaking, if it's 60% lined up, but solves the main problem inhibiting the question, it potentially provides useful enough information to be worth upvoting, but is too far away from being the intended question to be worth accepting. That's all.

Comment: @KyleBaker If an answer was 40% wrong (or missing 40% of what is needed for a correct answer) then that's a *very* wrong answer.  It almost certainly merits a downvote if it's that wrong/incomplete.

Comment: @Servy, Ok, tweak the numbers to suit your own preferences. Are you saying there is no gray area--it's either close enough to edit, or should not even be upvoted? Because that's not how I understand the upvote/downvote system to be used.

Comment: Could someone explain to me why I got hyper-downvoted instantly? Are downvotes in meta different than elsewhere or something? Did my question's tone get misinterpreted somehow? It was just an honest idea I had, I feel like I just got slapped for asking an honest question/honest proposal I didn't see elsewhere. Is upvoting/downvoting expected to be used for voting on whether they like the idea or not? I understand choosing not to upvote, but I don't understand what's so bad here that it merits a downvote, and it makes me gunshy of ever posting in meta again, frankly. :/

Comment: @KyleBaker If I felt an answer was a good answer to the question, I wouldn't feel compelled to write my own new answer.  If I felt that I needed to write my own answer to a question I would be doing so because I felt the existing answers weren't good answers to the question.  I may not consider them *bad* enough to downvote them, but if I felt that existing answers were good enough to merit an upvote, then that would mean I wouldn't feel enough was missing to need to add a new answer.

Comment: @KyleBaker meta downvotes on [meta-tag:feature-request] mean disagreement with the proposal.  We don't think it's a useful enough feature for developer time.  Yes [downvotes on meta are different](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251487/getting-to-know-stack-overflows-voting-culture)

Comment: @KyleBaker http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/272617/1159478

Comment: Ah, ok. Thank you, @ryanyuyu. Bit confusing given the way they're used elsewhere, but I suppose that makes sense.

Comment: @KyleBaker ryanyuyu's explanation is oversimplified to the point of being rather misleading.  I suggest you read through Shog's explanation of the behavior.  It's long, but it's absolutely worth the time, and provides a much more accurate representation of what's going on here.

Comment: @Servy, I was reading that post while you were typing. I read it all. Very helpful, but I think re-using the same system as exists elsewhere on the site is the source of this confusion. I have no problem with voting, but since voting 'means' something different here, it should have some UX differences so it doesn't 'feel' the same as downvoting feels elsewhere. Thank you very much for the link, that was very helpful. I'm sorry for how often you must have to post it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this would be a useful feature because we already have ways to reward good answers.

First, you should upvote helpful answers.  This immediately gives the answerer reputation.

You have no obligation to accept your own answer.  The accept mark is for showing that a problem has been solved or has sufficient progress to a resolution, so it's fine to just leave the accept mark with the other answer if it is so instrumental to the final solution.

If you really think that your self-answer is the *better* solution, then the other answer does not deserve the checkmark anyway.  After upvoting the helpful (imperfect) answer, if you still want to award more reputation, just award it a bounty.