# What do I when you got a question ban after a vote down rush?

Tags: discussion, support, banning

I was able to post a question, but someone disliked three of my OLD questions, so I can't ask a question any more.

Just look at the screen and you will see that someone searched for my old topic to get me banned. I had a disagreement with someone on the site, but doing that is really childish.

I think that's unfair. What can I do?

[image: Vote down rush]

Comment: The problem is that the ban won't go away, since I'm new, he just had to downvote some of my posts and as you can see, he clearly waited to dislike the 3rd time.

Comment: Then http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255583/3001761

Comment: I just go a dislike here :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41975355/how-to-stream-one-row-at-a-time-in-big-query-with-nodejs

Someone is clearly mocking me.

Comment: You don't get question banned for just one post. It's unfortunate if a series of revenge votes triggered the ban, and a reversal of the votes *should* lift you out again, but take it as a strong signal that you are on the edge and should improve your question quality from here on out if you want to avoid hitting the same problem again. I see you have a series of deleted questions, some of which have negative scores. It is **those posts** that are the real issue here.

Comment: Not that you were the victim of a revenge vote series as far as I can make out. Two votes at one point, another vote 6 hours later, is not a series.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I did a bad post when I started stackoverflow, and I got like -4, I deleted it and I know it still count. But now I have 4 questions left and they all got disliked.. I think it doesn't help and it's just isn't fair.

Comment: @SuperBoy well that is indisputably a bad question; even self-answered posts must meet the quality guidelines. Also see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269349/3001761.

Comment: You did attract more attention towards your posts by posting on Meta; this is called the [Meta effect](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251487/getting-to-know-stack-overflows-voting-culture). More people looking at your questions and judging their quality is not necessarily a good thing.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I see, but that doesn't change the fact that someone votedown my old post, right ?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Unfortunatly.. I think that I just won't stay on stackoverflow, it seems that I'm not made for it.

Comment: @SuperBoy the crucial point is whether or not you were the victim of *serial voting*, which is against the rules. Otherwise, people are free to vote as they see fit.

Comment: @jonrsharpe People are free to vote, it's obvious, I'm just complaining about a serial downvoting.

Comment: @SuperBoy two votes dont constitute serial voting. The third one could have been completely random and unrelated. You cannot know that they are cast by the same person.

Comment: What ever you do, don't vandalize your post on main. That makes things worse, not better...

Comment: Its k, I deleted my tutorial, I don't want it to help your community.

Comment: @SuperBoy: that doesn't give you the right to remove your posts however. They were licensed as CC Wiki when you posted, and together with the answers form a collective work now. The decision to remove or leave the posts is up to the site, not you.

Comment: Tell that to the quality tutorial I've just deleted. Cry me a river.

Comment: You're doing much more damage by deleting your posts -- especially if they are upvoted and accepted answers. The system will detect serial downvoting and reverse all of that automatically; people don't just get away with revenge downvoting...

Comment: Actually, they did. Stackoverflow is awesome, but the majority of the community I've met is bad, so bad. I owe you nothing, I leave, no one (should) care. This site is ruined by Intellectual masturbation. Funny to see that stackoverflow was created to counter the bad community of Experts-Exchange. I will just stay as guest and enjoy stackoverflow for it's content not his community.

Comment: Always best to sleep on things before making rash decisions. If you're here long enough, you *will* get serial down-votes, but wait a couple of days, and you will see that they go away. No biggie.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels You are absolutly right, but I don't want to deal with that part of the community anymore.

Comment: Of course it's up to you, but we hope you eventually change your mind.

Comment: @SuperBoy The main problem with EE that they wanted to address was that the information was hidden behind a walled garden, and wasn't accessible publicly for everyone.  Your argument that you want to keep your content to itself and not share it with anyone while SO wants to keep the information publicly available is not demonstrating any contradiction in SO's values.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Which they were more people like you on the board, thanks to make it better. I will stick to /sci/ on 4chan, even there, they are less annoying people.

Comment: Nah, I'm as bad as they come. I have poor patience for homework dumpers for instance.

Answer (score 3):

If voting is indeed fraud the system will revert it and after that you can try asking again.

The ban - if it was triggered by reverted votes - will go away when you try.

At MSE a Stack Exchange Community Manager [explained when question bans apply](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/252645/165773):

> ...ban is applied when a user who qualifies for it tries to ask a question. Until that point, they're like [that cat in a box](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger%27s_cat), both banned and unbanned...