# Can't understand a negative vote

Tags: discussion, downvotes

I have been asking and answering some questions on Stack Overflow since last year and I hope I have spent enough time on it to understand what is a useful answer and what is not.

Sometimes, I really don't understand the negative votes. For example, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44382336/having-issues-with-if-else-statements-python/44382380#44382380) that I wrote today got a downvote without any comment with a reasoning.

Stack Overflow Help says:

> What is voting down?
>
> Voting down, also known as "casting downvotes", is how the community
>   indicates which questions and answers are least useful.

My answer to that question was the first one there and directly answered what was asked. Others who answered later may have given descriptive answers which may be *more* useful than mine, but why downvote another correct answer? Downvoting a *repeat* correct answer makes sense, but that was not the case here.

I have seen this in the past as well where downvotes don't have an apparent reasoning, but over time I have also seen upvotes on the same question/answer to nullify those.

I know this question has been asked on Meta in the past too, but I am asking it here to specifically request folks to look at the answer I posted and tell me if they agree with the downvote, because if people do, then it would be good to learn my mistake here and avoid repeating it in the future.

Comment: I don't know why you were downvoted.  All my own answers are perfect and cannot possibly be faulted, but some get downvoted.  Go figure..  :)

Comment: Compare it to the accepted answer - They don't only say what's wrong, they also provide a solution (While your answer don't) - I didn't downvote your answer, but I can understand why other users did

Comment: Thanks to everyone who responded but I did not realise I will get so many _more_ downvotes! Will it look indecent if I delete this question or the answer being talked about in this question?

Comment: @Anupam - It's fine to delete it though if you leave this Meta question up, quoting your answer here before removing it would allow users below 10K to still see what you were asking about. (Asking about a post on Meta tends to cause more people to vote on it. It's called the [Meta effect](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251488/4076315)).

Comment: @BSMP, I have deleted the answer now and left a comment there with the reason of deleting. Also earned the 'Peer Pressure' badge as a result :) so it seems to be ok.

Comment: You gotta fight the haters man. Every user that down votes you is an enemy that you must annihilate. Never back down, never give up. Have you ever been in a debate club?

Answer (score 20):

Your answer is at best incomplete as it only re-confirms what the OP already explained /noticed.

The OP and, more important,  future visitors are more helped if you don't only explain why they got that error but also provide possible solutions (in code, this is after all a programming site) how to conquer that functional issue.

Looking at that question I'm a bit surprised there isn't a proper duplicate for that question.

For your information: it is not only your answer that was down voted, all answers are, including the two now deleted answers. And the question got 4 down votes. I blame that on being trivial.

Answer (score 11):

Your answer was too terse and the code not fully explained. I had to read it twice to work out what you meant. If you had explicitly used the words "case significance" or "upper case" and "lower case" or "capitalised" then it might have been clearer.

The questioner obviously had not spotted the difference in case in the string in the first place, so not drawing attention to it in your answer is an omission in your answer.

---

<sub>Just for clarity here: I have not voted on the [SO] question being discussed. I have only looked at it for the first time as a meta reader and am offering my opinion on why some readers may have felt the answer was inadequate, purely as a guidance for the OP.</sub>