# Should I flag a comment "begging" for votes?

Tags: discussion, support

There is a user that -after I answered [his question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48320328/is-there-any-way-to-update-table-record-in-every-x-minutes-without-any-trigger-i/48321238#comment83628774_48321238)- wrote that he *"expect me to upvote his question"* because he marked my answer as accepted and probably voted it up too. I think this isn't very appropriate and probably not even considered polite, but should I flag it as `not nice/ no longer needed` or something? It is kind of a "like-for-like" situation which I think is strictly against the community guidelines. I thought I´ve seen somewhere that you shouldn't beg for likes?

> What I did so far (and if there isn't a final answer will keep doing): I commented referencing the [upvote priviledge article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) and said that I don't think that this post is a major contribution to the network as the question was pretty open and maybe even broad plus answered in a similar question.

Comment: Pro tip: Don't answer bad questions to begin with. =/ That question is _terrible_ in terms of site quality. Personally, I think it should be closed.

Comment: @Kendra You are probably right. I normally edit such questions or ask to clarify and adjust according to the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) but this time I just answered it. Thanks for the help

Comment: And sorry @Glorfindel for my obviously incomplete research, I didn't see this post when searching for the answer... Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: The question should be deleted as well as it's a very low quality common duplicate.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Just out of curiosity: Did you just downvote my answer? :D Is it bad practice or even against the guidelines to answer such a bad post?

Comment: Yes I did (here come the revenge votes). That question and his comments were nothing but a beg for code, for information that is easy to find, that is already present on this site. Again, we shouldn't even answer that question, but quickly close it, delete it, and not encourage it from happening again by answering it. Sorry, but my 2 cents.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels What are revenge votes? :D I thought so. I will keep that in mind and wont answer such questions in the future. I just thought that I could help him (and probably did)...

Comment: FYI: I've also placed a request in the SOCVR for that question to be deleted.

Comment: Question is now gone

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Oh! You mean that I will downvote questions of you because you downvoted mine? :D I would never do such a thing. This would be completely against the community goal (and so on) and pretty much a very rude move...

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Seen it. Thanks for taking care of this :)

Comment: y/w I made sure to reference this meta discussion as well, so that folks could read this before making a vote as it is pertinent.