# Where can I send improvement suggestions or feature requests? The "How to Ask" guidance on Meta is confusing

Tags: bug, status-completed, asking-questions, meta

Is there a way to send Stack Overflow improvement suggestions, like feature requests?

I thought I had to do this here on Meta, but when I started to Ask a question I saw in the yellow square on the right:

> We prefer questions that can be *answered*, not just discussed

[image: Screenshot of the yellow square on the right]

So what if I just want to suggest an improvement? Is that okay here?

Comment: You found it, congratulation.

Comment: Huh.  Meta is all *about* discussion.  This feels like a bug.

Comment: The [discussion] tag is the most commonly used tag at meta, almost 3 times as common as the next popular one, [support].  Sounds to me you want [feature-request].  It is somewhat likely to be discussed anyway.

Comment: That text is just a copy-paste from the main site. It should probably be changed, since it doesn't make much sense for Meta.

Comment: Before posting a [feature-request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/feature-request/info) please do read the tag info page. It gives a number of hints as to the necessary content of such a post.

Comment: Required reading before posting a feature request: [Can we talk about the voting culture here on Meta?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272607/4639281)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Huh... That bit of text was woefully out of date.

I've reverted it to the default guidance that appears on other per-site metas:

> **Is your question about the [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com) community or website?**
>
> Provide details. Show examples.
>
> Whenever possible, link to the relevant questions, answers, users, or page on the site you're discussing.
>
> [visit the help center »](/help)

Sorry for the confusion, and thanks for reporting this!

Comment: I'm a bit concerned about the *link to the relevant .... you're discussing* part, @Shog, regarding the [meta effect](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251488/4099593). Would it be possible to reword it slightly keeping that in mind? (I'm not sure of a way to do that, but you'd certainly know).

Comment: The alternative is nearly always worse, @BhargavRao. A discussion in abstract tends to just be folks talking past each other.