# Should parallel versions of this question be created for other programming languages?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, canonical

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors) seems to be a useful dupe target for basic Java questions about debugging. It was written a long time ago and was apparently created intentionally as a reference for exactly that sort of thing.

I was unable to find an equivalent question for Python, or for any other language for that matter. I frequently run into beginner questions in the [python] tag that seem either seem like they should be dupe-hammered with such a question, or given the link for reference. However, the Java question as written seems quite language-specific. I would rather not refer people to examples in another language expect them to figure out what does or doesn't apply.

Did I overlook equivalents for Python or other languages? If not, is it worthwhile to start them? Would it be better to discuss the topic in a language-agnostic way? (I lean against this because the examples will look different in different languages; but I imagine I could be convinced otherwise.)

I was thinking that in addition to explaining the use of exception/stack traces, it would be a good idea to include check-lists for the most common causes of various common exception types, and/or some basic approaches to fixing them (e.g. for a division-by-zero error, re-consider whether division is actually the desired operation, and consider whether it makes sense for the expression used in the denominator to become zero, and consider whether this should be an explicitly handled corner case...) Thoughts?

Comment: Maybe helpful: [Getting to Know Stack Overflow's Voting Culture](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251487/11682469) (from the [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251488/11682469): "On **Meta**, users generally vote based on their perception of the **quality of the post** (well researched/high value/interesting/correct) or, absent quality issues, if the user believes that the post contains a proposal, **the premise of the post** (agreement).")

Comment: Even if I try to take my ego out of it, that policy still makes absolutely no sense to me. For example, *why does the "can't delete when there's an upvoted answer" rule still apply?* If proposals that people think are a bad idea, are supposed to get hidden (the net effect of downvoting, by design), then how is it helpful to prevent them from being cleaned up? On the other hand, if it's relevant and useful to future viewers to highlight the answer(s) explaining what's bad about the proposal, then how does it help to demote the question?

Comment: At the very least, I think it can be useful as a reference and dupe target. In case similar suggestions come up in the future. Previous discussions regarding similar and or/related subjects can be referenced and give additional context. The reception (positive or negative) previous discussions had serve to inform what some part of the community thought of some idea at a particular point in time.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel well... culture isn't really the same as a policy. I personally say that voting on meta works in mysterious ways, which does not imply good or bad (because it's both good and bad).  My guess is that the restrictions you speak of are no more than a side effect of the fact that meta runs on the same software as the main Q&A site.

Answer (score 12):

No.

A stack trace is a stack trace regardless of the language or environment.

There may be differences in how the information is presented, but the basic information is the same - it's a list of the current methods called up to the point the program was stopped, or crashed.

Comment: So "common remedies for Python-specific errors" is a separate topic, then? Or is that considered outside of scope now? I remember being quite excited about that attempt at a documentation project. Sometimes it seems like the site/culture goes out of its way to avoid providing useful information that it could easily do.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel is there something really specific to Python stack traces? I can see there being a need for other questions about other types of error, but I don't see a need in this case.

Comment: For example, to explain the common causes of `TypeError` (Python-specific in that other languages would check the types at compile time). The purpose of the question is to explain how to use the trace to help identify and solve the problem; the type of error mentioned is part of that information.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel - that could be useful, but it's not related to a stack trace - unless I'm missing something here.

Answer (score 8):

No, but....

---

First off, having a generic "all I got was this lousy Python(*) traceback" Q&A does not seem useful.

- It is a RTFM duplicate. When using it as a duplicate for a debugging question, we do not say how to fix a problem – we say how to *learn how to* fix a problem.
- It is a bottomless pit. There's explicit and implicit exception chaining, there's upcoming [concurrent failures](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0654/), there's rewriting, there's builtins eating traces, there's ...
- It is too generic. A traceback just says *where* things went wrong: how to fix that will vary widely between a `TypeError`, `ValueError` and `KeyError`; between a function, generator or coroutine; between...
- It is often not helpful. The trace of a `KeyError` does usually not say why some other function thrice removed loaded the wrong key from a JSON.

---

That said, there are many *individual* problems that could be well addressed via *several* Q&As, some of them including tracebacks.

- A general "what does a traceback say" for the people actually wondering what a traceback says.
- Some *specific problem* cases, such as "why does a generator traceback point to a function that is already done?", or "why does a traceback refer to 'the above exception'?".
- ...

Importantly, a generic "how to debug with a traceback" canonical still has merit as a "soft dupe": suggest it as a duplicate for obscure debugging questions, and let the OP decide whether it answers their question.
Just do not use it as an excuse to RTFM-hammer.

---

(*) May apply to other languages.

Comment: **"Just do not use it as an excuse to RTFM-hammer"** - I quoted it, so now it is truth.